# Explicit description of a metric topology

Tags: general-topology

> Consider the set $X := \{z,w\} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Now
>   $(X,|\cdot|)$ is a metric space where $|\cdot|$ is the standard metric
>   on $\mathbb{C}$. How does the metric topology on $X$ look like, i.e.
>   the collection of open sets in the sense of the metric?

I think it must be $\mathcal{T} = \{\varnothing,\{z\},\{w\},X\}$. Is that correct?

Comment: If $z\ne w$ let $r=|z-w|/2 .$  Then open ball of radius $ r,$ centered at $z$, is just $\{z\},$ and the open ball of radius $r,$ centered at $w,$ is just $\{w\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any [metric space is Hausdorff](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862598). Any [finite Hausdorff space is discrete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567152/).

As $X=\{z,w\}$ is finite and is a metric space, it must be discrete and the topology is therefore $\mathcal T=\mathcal P(X)$, which is exactly the one you wrote.

Comment: Thanks. That was the proposition I was looking for! +1