# Finite Hausdorff space is totally disconnected

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

A space is said to be totally disconnected if its only connected subsets are one point sets.

To show that finite Hausdorff space is totally disconnected.

Can anyone give some hints.

Comment: [A finite Hausdorff space is discrete](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1567152)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose a finite Hausdorff space $X$ had a connected subset $C$ with $n>1$ distinct points, say $x_1, \cdots, x_n$. Being Hausdorff, there exists disjoint open sets $U_1$ and $V_2$ in $X$ such that $x_1\in U_1$ and $x_2\in V_2$. Similarly there exists disjoint open sets $U_2$ and $V_3$ such that $x_1\in U_2$ and $x_3\in V_3$ and so on there exists disjoint open sets $U_{n-1}$ and $V_n$ such that $x_1\in U_{n-1}$ and $x_n\in V_n$. Then $\cup_{i=2}^n(C\cap V_i)$ and $\cap_{i=1}^{n-1} (C\cap U_i)$ forms a separation of $C$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: This proof is wrong. Why should $C\cap U$ and $C\cap V$ cover $C$? The fact that you didn't use finiteness should be a big red flag that you're missing something.

Comment: Well $C$ can contain finitely many more points but I can still separate one from the others right?

Comment: Yes, you can continue your proof in that way.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Is this ok?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

A finite Hausdorff space is discrete and all discrete spaces are zero dimensional.

Comment: This is the right proof!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Any point of a Hausdorff space forms a closed subset.